# Java. Из JSON в XML без научной (экспоненциальной) формы записи чисел

Tags: java, json, xml, парсер

Имеется следующая задача/проблема.
С сервера получаю ответ в виде JSON'a.
С помощью **Java** необходимо перевести этот **JSON** в строку, содержащую валидный **XML**.

Изначально использовал **org.Json**. Он умеет и json парсить из строки, и распарсенный JSON в XML переводить. 
Всё бы хорошо, но эта библиотека преобразует большие/длинные числа в экспоненциальную (научную) форму, что в конечной XML строке мне НЕ нужно. Как выводить числа в нормальном виде при помощи org.json я так и не понял.
Далее попробовал **Gson**. Он парсит JSON без всяких экспонент *(у него даже есть соответствующая настройка)*, но вот преобразовать gson в XML не сообразил как. =_=

Наверняка кто-то уже решал подобную проблему? Подскажите, пожалуйста, рецепт перевода JSON в XML на Java, сохраняя числа в нормальном виде.

И да, с сервера Json не содержит не каких экспонент, там все в нормальном виде приходит.

P.S. Было бы идеально, если указанный ответ-решение нормализовал и те числа, которые с сервера придут в научной форме *(ну а вдруг таки придут?)*, но это уже дополнительно и необязательно:)

Comment: Вариант `JSON->Gson->объект(набор классов)->JAXB->XML` не вариант?

Comment: А оно сумеет адекватно сделать из **gson.JSONObject** XML, соотносящееся с исходным JSON?

Comment: `JAXB`? Конечно. Тут главное правильно составить набор классов, куда и будет, собственно, парсится сначала `JSON` а потом `XML`

Answer (score 0):

Могу предложить библиотеку [underscore-java](https://github.com/javadev/underscore-java). У неё есть статический метод `U.jsonToXml(json)`.